# Symfony2 PHPunit testing functions which gets user object from token storage

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I know this question is already asked but I can't get it to work and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to write a test for a function which depends on a user logged in and gets user object from `security.token_storage` but unfortunately I can't get it work. For setting up the token my code is

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
    $person, 
    $person->getPassword(), 
    'sso', 
    $person->getRoles()
);

$containerInterface->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

$containerInterface->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(
    AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS,
    new AuthenticationEvent($token)
);
```

where `$person` is user object and `'sso'` is firewall name. When I run a test where I get user object from token_storage I get null.

Comment: You want to simulate a login? Because now you're not.

Comment: Kind of. I need to be able to get user object like that: `$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're missing the login event

```
$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

Also, but I'm not sure of, you don't need this snippet

```
$containerInterface->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(
    AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS,
    new AuthenticationEvent($token)
);
```